# How to remove duplicates with out using Row_num,Distinct,Groupby or having

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sample data like this which only have `varchar` values and it doesn't have ID column:

```
Name 
Mohan
Mohan
Mohan
Mohan
```

Required output:

```
Name
Mohan
```

How can this be achieved *using only a Correlated Sub query*.
I have tried with below query:

```
DELETE table  
WHERE name < ( SELECT MAX(name) FROM table t
WHERE t.name = name  )
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Tip: Use table aliases for all tables...

Comment: I'd create another table and copy the distinct values there.

Comment: Create a new table WITH a PK, and a UNIQUE name column

Comment: MSSQL I'M USING

Comment: @Strawberry in table level I don't want I want in query level mostly with Co-related sub query

Comment: Why it is getting down voted I don't have a clue. I have given clear details and sample query what I have tried so far

Comment: *Why* does this have to be sub-query only?

Comment: it is a requirement i need to achieve in sub query ..@iamdave

Comment: do you have unique/pk key in this table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use the undocumented(!) `%%physloc%%` pseudo column, which describes the physical location of a row, to identify a row. For example, only keep the row with the minimal `%%physloc%%`.

```
DELETE FROM elbat
            WHERE %%physloc%% <> (SELECT min(%%physloc%%)
                                         FROM elbat t
                                         WHERE t.name = elbat.name);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7f325c55fb39a7efc87afb38fb1084ae)

But, as already mentioned, `%%physloc%%` is undocumented and therefore subject to change or removal without further notice in future patches or releases. You query might break suddenly.

Comment: but the problem hers is if I add any other name it is still giving single column

Comment: @mohan111: There is only one column, so of course there is only a single column. If you meant you inserted other rows (= names), it still remove the duplicates for other names too. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=70edc6dd625f5c5e21b693eaa4d0b645

Comment: but it is not working with table variable just execute from your side

Comment: @mohan: Yes it does: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=fb852aafe56ea483313a186784f59fe4

Answer (score 1):

Without "CTE, ROW_NUM, Distinct, Group by, having count(*)" you can use UNION:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Value varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES ('Name'), ('Mohan'), ('Mohan'), ('Mohan'), ('Mohan');

SELECT Value FROM @Data
UNION
SELECT Value FROM @Data
```

Comment: I have mentioned in question already. Need this one in sub query or Co-related sub query

Comment: Might be worth adding `where 1=0` to your second `select` to limit the processing and data retrieval required.

Comment: @mohan111  This solution doesn't use any of the functionality you have mentioned.  Are you saying that you want a solution that *only* uses subqueries?

Comment: @iamdave yes absolutely you are correct I need it sub query

Answer (score 1):

Besides sticky bit's solution using `%%physloc%%`, I don't see a way to do this via a correlated subquery when the table doesn't have a primary key.

But here's an alternative with a sub-query that comes near.

```
DELETE t FROM 
(
  select row_number() over (partition by name order by name) as rn 
  from [Table]
) t
WHERE rn > 1;
```